# WildFly 8 Logging Levels

Tags: wildfly, wildfly-8

How do I modify the WildFly 8 logging levels, specifically server.log. Currently I suspect they default to INFO and would like to change it to Debug or Error.

For reference I've been exploring these articles

https://docs.jboss.org/author/display/WFLY8/Logging+Configuration

https://docs.jboss.org/author/display/WFLY8/How+To

And suspect this is correct;

```
<subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:logging:2.0">
            <console-handler name="CONSOLE">
                <level name="DEBUG"/>
                <formatter>
                    <named-formatter name="COLOR-PATTERN"/>
```

Answer (score 9):

By default the `console-handler` is set to `INFO` and the `FILE` handler does not have a level set. The `root-logger` is also set to `INFO`.

The instructions on the How To page you link so you how to add a new logger via CLI and assign it a level. If you were to add a new logger at a `DEBUG` level, then the `server.log` would get those log messages written to it.

If you want to change the `root-logger` to see `DEBUG` messages for all loggers that are not defined you can execute the following command.

```
/subsystem=logging/root-logger=ROOT:write-attribute(name=level,value=DEBUG)
```

If you want to also see messages on the console you need to change the level on the handler.

```
/subsystem=logging/console-handler=CONSOLE:write-attribute(name=level,value=DEBUG)
```

I wouldn't advocate using editing the XML. Using a management interface such as CLI or the web console is the appropriate way to change server settings.

Answer (score 1):

Just change the level of the root-logger and the one of the console logger. For a first shot this should work.