# WELD-000119: Not generating any bean definitions from because of underlying class loading error

Tags: java, debugging, jsf, deployment, wildfly

I'm new in using MyEclipse and Java EE

I'm trying to deploy my web application on wildfly 8.0.0. in MyEclipse.

Unfortunately, I'm getting this error after I took some code changes from SVN (I'm not sure this is the reason), before that it was working fine:

```
[org.jboss.weld.Bootstrap] (weld-worker-2) WELD-000119: Not generating any bean definitions from (.....) because of underlying class loading error: Type WebArchive from [Module "deployment.Test.war:main" from Service Module Loader] not found.  If this is unexpected, enable DEBUG logging to see the full error.
```

When I (Run) the server, the deployment succeeded although the console produces some lines of the same error, but when i (Debug) the server, it keeps generating the same error.

Can someone help me please

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was because I'm starting my server in debug mode and the breakpoints were activated

Answer (score 2):

It may be that the class loader can't find "WebArchive" because it needs to be added as a module to the WildFly configuration. You do that like this:

```
module add --name=org.apache.commons.lang3.commons-lang3 --resources=C:\Users\b\.m2\repository\org\apache\commons\commons-lang3\3.4\commons-lang3-3.4.jar
```

In addition, you'll probably need to add WebArchive as a dependency in the `<build>` section of your pom.xml.

Here's the relevant section of my pom.xml:

```
  <build>
    <!-- Maven will append the version to the finalName (which is the name
        given to the generated WAR, and hence the context root) -->
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>${version.war.plugin}</version>
            <configuration>
            <!-- Java EE doesn't require web.xml, Maven needs to catch up! -->
                <failOnMissingWebXml>false</failOnMissingWebXml>
                <archive>
                    <manifestEntries>
                        <Dependencies>com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype.jackson-datatype-jsr310,org.hibernate,org.apache.commons.lang3.commons-lang3</Dependencies>
                    </manifestEntries>
                </archive>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <!-- The WildFly plug-in deploys the WAR to a local WildFly container -->
        <!-- To use, run: mvn package wildfly:deploy -->
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.wildfly.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>wildfly-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>${version.wildfly.maven.plugin}</version>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

If you can't figure it out, try posting your pom.xml and jboss-deployment-structure.xml (if you have one).

Comment: BTW, I'm doing quite a bit of guessing here. What would help a lot is posting your pom.xml.

Answer (score 0):

This error message does not hint to start your server in debug mode, but to set the log level of org.jboss.weld.Bootstrap or the root logger to debug. 
See [WildFly 8 Logging Levels](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26262702/jboss-8-logging-levels) for how to do that

Comment: Do you have any "underlying class loading error" log messages listed in that log output?  BTW, I don't think turning on additional logging is going to help.